# dagger 2 initialize parameterized acitivity consrtuctor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

How to initialize constructor of activity using dagger 2.

I am trying to add parameter in activity constructor signature in activitymodule but it does not allow to add parameters in constructor due to @ContributesAndroidInjector annotation

`@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = FragmentModule.class)
    MainActivity contributeMainActivity();`

Also I don't want to do field injection. I would like to achieve constructor injection like below of Activity.

`public MainActivity(DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> dispatchingAndroidInjector) {
        mDispatchingAndroidInjector = dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }`

Thanks.

Comment: You never construct an activity directly, so you can't use it to pass in parameters. Generally, just do things in onCreate

Comment: instead of injecting DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> as a field. I would like to directly inject it in constructor. What is wrong in it. Is it documented on android official sites to never construct an activity directly ?

Comment: Activities are constructed by the framework. You should not build them yourself. That's why we need to use field injection unfortunately.